# error C2664: 'void RegisterPlugins(flutter::PluginRegistry *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'flutter::FlutterViewController *'

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter, dart

I upgraded my flutter to the latest version and since then I have been getting this error: [console output of android studio on running flutter build windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruyqd.png)

This is my flutter doctor output :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-4.0.pre.102, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-4.0.pre.102 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f5ce638959 (44 minutes ago), 2020-10-27 14:44:50 -0700
    • Engine revision 64e6599910
    • Dart version 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-260.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Amit Madgi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.2)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.7.30413.136
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Amit Madgi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows    • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572]
    • Web Server (web)  • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.111

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the windows folder and ran flutter create . which recreated everything needed to build the windows app and it worked. I assume there were conflicts in the windows folder of the previous version that prevented from building this one successfully.